# Condição para nome do arquivo

Tags: pandas, if, condição

Preciso fazer a seguinte condição caso o nome do arquivo, que é um .json, tenha os caracteres *VG*, *AP* ou *GM* em pandas:

```
    if name_arquivo.str.contains('_VG_') or name_arquivo.str.contains('_AP_') or name_arquivo.str.contains('_GM_'):
         df_s3['PremioTotal'] = df_s3.apply(
            lambda x: [coberturas['PremioTotal'] for coberturas in x.Coberturas], 
            axis=1, 
            result_type='expand')
```

Porém estou obtendo o seguinte erro:

*AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'*

Alguém pode me ajudar, por favor?

Comment: Pouca informação para responder a pergunta. Apenas uma suposição: A variável `name_arquivo` deve ser do tipo string. Sendo assim o `if` deveria ser `if "_VG_" in name_arquivo or "_AP_" in name_arquivo or "_GM_" in name_arquivo:`

Comment: Não funcionou. O problema é o seguinte: nos arquivos que possuem essas letras nos nomes, eu preciso abrir um array para tirar o campo de Prêmio Total, que está na coluna Coberturas. Para os demais arquivos, esse campo já está disponível, sem precisar extrair. Todos os arquivos estão na mesma pasta.